# Firebase storage 'getBytes' doesn't have a cancel method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am downloading a json file from storage using 'getBytes', but I want to cancel the download if it took more than 10 seconds. the method 'getBytes' returns a a 'Task' type which doesn't have a cancel method, unlike 'getFile' which returns 'FileDownloadTask' that indeed has a cancel method.
So, Is there a way to cancel the download using 'getBytes', Can I cast 'Task' to 'FileDownloadTask' ?

Edit: Here is my code :

```
mainStorageRef.child(UNIVERSITIES_DATA_STORAGE_PATH).getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            String jsonData = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            ...
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            FastUtils.toastAndLogConnectionFailure(context, e);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

As far as I can see from the (closed source) implementation, the task that you get back from `getBytes()` is **not** a `FileDownloadTask`. It is instead a direct `Task<byte[]>` that is constructed by a [`TaskCompletionSource` object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource). For that reason, it can't be cancelled.

Your request seems reasonable though, so I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to make the engineering team aware of it.

For the moment, I'd recommend using the [`getStream()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getStream()), which gives you a `StreamDownloadTask` task that can be cancelled. You can then read the stream contents into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which is pretty much what the `getBytes` method does internally.

Comment: Ok I filed the feature request

Comment: Can you please provide the code needed for getStream, I updated my question.

Comment: The source for getBytes() is publicly available here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.java#L407

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I didn't even know we'd open-sourced that too. 